# Adding unit test to JavaFXPorts project in NetBeans - issue with Retrolambda

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, gluon, javafxports

I found some help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656154/how-to-setup-junit-testing-in-gluon-project-with-gradle/35745318#35745318). So I know that I must use JDK7 in order for unit testing to work.. So I came up with a build sript like this:

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies 
    {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

retrolambda.oldjdk = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79'

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies 
{
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

mainClassName = 'AppMain' 

jfxmobile 
{
    javafxportsVersion = '8.60.7'
    android 
    {
        applicationPackage = 'com.somename.someapplication'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk' //
    }
}
```

But i keep getting this exception:

```
Could not get unknown property 'retrolambda' for root project
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply the jfxmobile plugin first, which in turn will add the retrolambda dependency. Then you can configure the retrolambda oldJdk variable. 
(Pay attention for the camelCase spelling)

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies 
    {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'java'

retrolambda.oldJdk = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_79'
```